# how avoid asking for FB.api('/me', function (user)) for each page

Tags: facebook

i am developing a web-site using Facebook-connect for the login.
My site has several pages, and in each of them i need to do

> FB.api('/me', function (user))

to get the user. But in this way in each page i must wait Facebook to answer.

Which is the best way to do it, logging the user just in the first page and passing the info among the other pages?

thank you

Comment: How about doing it once when the user first logs in and then saving in the database and/or the server session?

Comment: it's a javascript object. i don't need just the user id, but the whole object. So i would discard the database option.  For the server session...do you mean use the sessions in php?

Comment: What difference does it make if it's a js object or a number? If you need to re-use the data just save it. js objects can be easily encoded into strings (it's called json) and so serializing/deserializing is really easy. As for session, yeah, I mean the sessions in php (in case you are working with php on the server)

Comment: mmm you are right... i can save just the fields i need into a string in json format. Or is there a way to auto-encode it? (the opposite of 'eval' i guess).   But in this way, if i log-out from facebook, i don't log-out from my web-site...  i don't know if it can be a problem actually...probably yes.

Comment: I have no idea what language you are using, but most languages today have some sort of json libraries to use. Different implementations provide different functionality, but most will let you encode/decode json to/from strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a header called in all your pages with the FB.api code and just change the content of your pages (Sort of children pages)

Comment: mm.. I didn't get it actually..    Do you mean use iframes?

Comment: In order to answer, you have to tell me how exactly did you manage your website ? Which framework did you use ?

Comment: my site is in html5, so it uses html and javascript on the client side and php on server side. For 'sort of children pages', do you mean use a dynamic page?  But in this way i can't use several link for my pages, isn't it?

Comment: Yes a dynamic page exactly. Why couldn't you use links ? Which sort of links are you talking about ?

Comment: i have my page (www.mysite.com). if i click on 'about us', i don't go to www.mysite.com/aboutus but i stay on the main page, i just change its content. If i have to link the 'about us' page outside my site, i can't (i think so)

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you. If your website works like that, you have a main page always there. So just put you fb.api in there and it will work in all pages

Comment: but i need to link the several pages outside my site...   for example, i need to link to www.mysite.com/aboutus      so i think your solution doesn't feet for me. thank you anyway :)